# Import CSV file generated from Excel To LaTeX with Datatool with accent

Tags: datatool, csv, excel

I'm trying to import a .CSV file generated with excel that contais special characters as `á, é, í, ó, ú`.
I'm using `\DTLloadrawdb`, but these characters still don't show.
What is the magic trick to do this?
My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xifthen}
%\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}/


\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLrawmap{á}{\'{a}}
\DTLrawmap{é}{\'{e}}
\DTLrawmap{í}{\'{i}}
\DTLrawmap{ó}{\'{o}}
\DTLrawmap{ú}{\'{u}}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloadrawdb{produtosAloe}{../EstudoMercado.csv}
\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloadrawdb{produtosValor}{../../Planilhas/prod.csv}
\title{Estudo de mercado}
\author{Glauco Goebel Tirollo}
\date{09 de Novembro de 2017}
\newcommand{\av}{\textit{Aloe Vera}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage



\input{EstudoMercado.tex}



\end{document}
```

And, if useful, my csv:

```
Company;Address;Description;Products;Website Natier;Buenos Aires,    
Argentina;A Natier é uma empresa de produtos naturais, entre eles a babosa. A empresa possui uma variedade   muito grande de produtos, com loja online e pontos físicos espalhados pela argentina.;Liofilizado;https://www.tiendanatier.com.ar aloe explotaciones;Andalucía, Espanha;Grupo dedicado ao cultivo e produção de Aloe Vera ecol\'{o}gico e seus derivados. Seus produtos   seguem os padrões de qualidade ditados pela União Européia. ;Plantas, folhas, gel, suco e liofilizados.;aloeexplotaciones.com Alibaba;China;Website chinês de busca de fornecedores.;Aloe Vera liofilizada em p\'{o};https://spanish.alibaba.com Veracetis;Madrid, Espanha;Veracetis é uma empresa de base tecnol\'{o}gica, surgida na Universidade de Alcalá, e apresenta um  novo conceito de produtos de consumos obtidos a partir de extratos vegetais bem como a  aplicação  destes extratos em diversos setores.  Possuem produção totalmente nacional, e é a primeira empresa europeia com registro sanitário e registro de agricultura ecol\'{o}gica.  Possui um forte centro de PD&I, que possui mais de 20 anos de experiência.;Suco, \'{o}leo, extrato seco, azeite, cápsulas, etc.;http://www.veracetics.es The body shop;mundial;Empresa originalmente britânica, atualmente possui 160 lojas espalhadas por todo o mundo.  Possui uma gama enorme de produtos na área de saúde, higiene e bem estar. ;Tônico calmante facial, Creme hidratante, espuma de limpeza facial, loção, sabão, creme de barbear, creme p\'{o}s barba, chá de banho, esfoliantes, entre outros produtos.;https://www.thebodyshop.com The face shop;Coréia;Empresa originalmente coreana, atualmente possui mais de 2600 lojas em 29 países ao redor do   mundo. Possuem uma grande variedade de artigos de beleza baseados em principios ativos de plantas.;Sabonete líquido, máscara facial, gel calmante. ;https://thefaceshop.ca/ Neutrogena;Los Angeles, Calif\'{o}rnia, EUA;neutrogena é uma marca norte-americana que inclui produtos faciais, para a pele, para os cabelos e   colorações. Em 1994, foi comprada pela Johnson & Johnson. Seus produtos são vendidos internacionalmente.;Gel para acne, ;www.neutrogena.com.br Forever living;Madrid, Espanha;A FOREVER é a maior plantadora, processadora e distribuidora de Aloe Vera do mundo! ;Protetor Solar;foreverliving.com`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\DTLloadrawdb` is intended for CSV files that have been generated by a non-TeX aware tool that doesn't escape special characters (`&` `#` etc, but not `\`). The command locally redefines those characters so that they expand to literal rather than active characters so they don't cause a problem. This expansion means that if the CSV file also contains control sequences or other active characters, then fragile stuff can break. Version 2.29 of `datatool` now uses `\protected@xdef` rather than `\xdef` in `\DTLloadrawdb`, but if your CSV file contains LaTeX control sequences, then you shouldn't be using `\DTLloadrawdb` (because it's not raw non-TeX data).

If your CSV file doesn't contain `&` etc intended in a literal context then always use `\DTLloaddb` which doesn't perform any expansion. If the CSV file contains non-ASCII characters just make sure that the encoding is correctly set in the document before loading the data:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb{produtosAloe}{../EstudoMercado.csv}
```

The problem with your CSV file is that it contains a mixture of UTF-8 (`é`), literal special characters (`&`) and control sequences (`\'{o}`). You need to be consistent: if you use LaTeX markup then escape the special characters (change `PD&I` to `PD\&I` etc) or if you can't escape special characters then don't use LaTeX markup (change `ecol\'{o}gico` to `ecológico`). The first (escaping special characters) is the better method. For the second, make sure you have at least v2.29 which will protect the expansion of the active UTF-8 octets.